# Connecting homomorphism is Bockstein operation, construction of natural long exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $0 \to \pi \overset{f}{\to} \rho \overset{g}{\to} \sigma \to 0$ be an exact sequence of Abelian groups and let $C$ be a chain complex of flat Abelian groups. Write $H_*(C; \pi) = H_*(C \otimes \pi)$. Can anybody provide me a reference to or supply the construction of a natural long exact sequence$$\dots \to H_q(C; \pi) \overset{f_*}{\to} H_q(C; \rho) \overset{g_*}{\to} H_q(C; \sigma) \overset{\beta}{\to} H_{q-1}(C; \pi) \to \dots?$$

Comment: Don't you have a short exact sequence of complexes $0\to C\otimes \pi \to C\otimes \rho \to C\otimes \sigma \to 0$ by flatness of $C$? In this case this is just the usual long exact sequence associated to a short exact sequence of complexes.

Comment: keywords Allen Hatcher *Algebraic Topology* at https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/